# Author info does not show up when author has no posts

Tags: functions, author, multi-author

When author has no posts, it does not display author name or bio (below code).
I tried http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Custom_Author_Information but it give me `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`.

This below code is in archive.php

```
<?php
    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
    the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );

    // Show an optional term description.
    $term_description = term_description();

    // Show author bio
    if ( is_author() ):
        get_template_part( 'author-bio' );
    endif;

    if ( ! empty( $term_description ) ) :
        printf( '<div class="taxonomy-description">%s</div>', $term_description );
    endif;
?>
```

author-bio.php

```
<div class="article-meta">
    <div class="author-avatar">
        <p>
        <?php
        /**
         * Filter the author bio avatar size.
         *
         * @param int $size The avatar height and width size in pixels.
         */
        $author_bio_avatar_size = apply_filters( 'simtiful_author_bio_avatar_size', 56 );

        echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), $author_bio_avatar_size );
        ?>
        </p>
    </div><!-- .author-avatar -->

    <div class="author-description">
        <h3 class="article-author"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></h3>

        <p class="author-bio">
            <?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?>
            <p>
            <a class="author-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">
                <?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'simtiful' ), get_the_author() ); ?>
            </a>
            </p>
        </p><!-- .author-bio -->

    </div><!-- .author-description -->
</div><!-- .author-info -->
```

Comment: Post the code from `author-bio.php`

Comment: so where is the error, what exactly you get in addition to the error?